# More storage in a Firefox addon with Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to develop an addon with the addon builder. I read that with simple storage one can have about 5 megabytes for his addon, but 5 mgb won't do it for my app. I need more. What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do much given the Add-on SDK API. Instead you could [break out of the sandbox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) and create a file in user's profile directory (see [File I/O code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO)). E.g. something along these lines to read the file `myData.txt` from user's profile:

```js
var {Cu, components} = require("chrome");
var {FileUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var {NetUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["myData.txt"]);

NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function(inputStream, status) {
  if (!components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
    // Handle error!
    return;
  }

  // The file data is contained within inputStream.
  // You can read it into a string with
  var data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
  console.log(data);
});
```

Note that the unusual syntax to import modules is due to [bug 683217](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683217).

Comment: There's also <https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/api-utils/docs/file.html>, but since that's an internal API, it's not really better than your answer.

Comment: @Nickolay: Yes, I didn't look at the internal APIs - I guess they aren't supposed to stay unchanged?

Comment: Right. The fixed link, since the comments are not editable: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/api-utils/docs/file.html