# how does a extension like autofill form save form data of a profile

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I was trying to develop a extension like autofill form .it looks simple but while implementing i got stuck at one point. how do we store data of a profile created permanently. i tried using localStorage in a javaScript to save data but its temporary.Any guidance would be very useful .Just show me the way i will reach the destination

```
function count()
{
 var inputs = $("input:text").length;
    alert("inputs are = "+inputs);

 var cnt = document.forms.length;

 alert(cnt);

 for (var a=0;a<document.forms.length;a++)
 {
  var x=0;
  var elem = document.forms[a].elements;
     for (x=0;x<document.forms[a].elements.length;x++)
  {
   //elem[x].value="Hello";
   if(x==0)
   {
    localStorage.setItem('userName', elem[x].value);    
   }
  }
  alert("Your user is: " + localStorage.getItem('userName'));
 }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think local storage is temporary? I mean, certainly the user can always clear it, but surely the user should be in control anyway.

Comment: related: [More storage in a Firefox addon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627312/more-storage-in-a-firefox-addon-with-add-on-sdk), [fartersoft.com: Using localStorage in Firefox Extensions for Persistent Data Storage](http://fartersoft.com/blog/2011/03/07/using-localstorage-in-firefox-extensions-for-persistent-data-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Preferences service to store the data in the user's profile. For example:

```
var prefService = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefService);
var prefs = prefService.getBranch("extensions.YOUREXTENSIONABBREVIATION.");

//elem[x].value = "Hello";
if (x==0) {
   prefs.setCharPref('userName', elem[x].value);
   prefService.savePrefFile(null);  
}
alert("Your user is: " + prefs.getCharPref('userName'));
```

For more information, look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension

Include a "defaults.js" file in the "defaults/preferences" folder of your extension. Initialize each item you're going to store in the preference file in case you try to retrieve something before it exists.